# Remove All But First String In Line

Tags: logging, notepad++

Hello I am trying to remove all but the first string in my text file.

Ex:

```
216.158.67.20 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.2.2; http://astrolog.iqsociety.org; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
188.165.206.161 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.1.1; http://www.giancarlocasaccia.com; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
173.192.21.195 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/3.6; http://elsieshop.com"
69.162.134.121 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.1.5; http://www.sexyliberal.com; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
192.254.140.214 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/3.5.1; http://www.kellenmeetings.com"
107.23.115.230 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.1.5; http://ccfi.com; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
204.9.45.175 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/3.3.2; http://www.successfulculture.com"
66.179.133.71 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.2.2; http://www.angelsunaware.com; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
76.74.128.150 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.1.5; http://www.rebeccaromero.co.uk; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
204.11.50.68 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/2992; http://favors.ca"
66.185.17.226 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/3.6.1; http://www.trulynaturalskincare.net"
199.204.248.103 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/3.5; http://riselocal.com.au"
82.195.224.110 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/2.8.6; http://blog.ioolkos.com"
82.161.251.86 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.0.5; http://www.terrabits.eu; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
184.154.89.138 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/3.9.3; http://websitevideocenter.com; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
64.65.60.129 - - [02/Jul/2015:13:46:02 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "WordPress/4.1; http://www.railroadphotoessays.com/essays; verifying pingback from 192.227.171.98"
```

I just want

```
216.158.67.20 
188.165.206.161 
173.192.21.195
```

etc...

Comment: This would be trivial with `cut`: `cut -f1 -d' ' filename`

Comment: Where would I run that command?

Comment: From a *nix command line, which I am guessing you don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with processing file line by line using C++

```
string line;

while (getline(file, line)) {
    line.erase(remove(line.begin() + line.find_first_of(' '), line.end()), line.end());
    ... // do anything with line
}
```

Since you have tagged `notepad++`, it can run python scripts. Try

```
file = open('logfile_name')
for line in file:
    print line.split()[0]
```

Find out how to run python scripts in notepad++ and use it.

Comment: What language is this?